# Hide/unhide a column based on a row value

Tags: excel, vba

I need to unhide Column E in case there is a "Camera AXIS check" value selected from a drop-down list within column B. I have gone through various Google searches and this is the code that I came up with, that I think would fit my requirements:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = [B7:B999] = "Camera AXIS check"
End Sub
```

However, whenever I try to check it, it doesn't like row 3.

Can someone please advise where did I go wrong?

To give more details about the task, Column B has these selections from row 7 and can have them up to unlimited amount of rows, whilst Column E is only appropriate to show up, whenever the selection in Column B is equal to "Camera AXIS check".

Comment: Please note that VBScript and VBA are not the same language.

Comment: If you are trying to unhide a column for only certain rows, that is not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the appropriate VBA Macro to accomplish what you need:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "Camera AXIS check" And Target.Column = 2 Then
    Columns("E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
        Columns("E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

If I understand the comments correctly, the column should stay unhidden if "Camera AXIS check" is anywhere in column "B". The following sub does the same as the above, but also tests if the value you're looking for is anywhere in the column, and if so does not re-hide the column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "Camera AXIS check" And Target.Column = 2 Then
    Columns("E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
        If IsError(Application.Match("Camera AXIS check", Range("B:B"), 0)) Then
            Columns("E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to add `And Target.Column=2` as this specifically was for Column B.

Comment: @DarrellH Good shout, in case the value shows up anywhere else. Answer edited.

Comment: Plutian, thank you very much. I owe you a beer. Same for Darrell H.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. And I might just hold you to that!

Comment: I have ran in to another issue, that if anything else in the row below is being selected than "Camera AXIS check", the column "E" tends to hide. Even though the first selection of "Camera AXIS check" have unhidden the column "E" in the first place. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. This code will unhide column "E" every time a value in column "B" is selected other than "Camera AXIS check". Only when this value is selected column "E" will be hidden. Due to the nature of `Worksheet_Change` this will trigger when you press `[ENTER]` in the cell, moving to the below cell (which might have a different value). If this is not what is needed, you might want to swap it to `Worksheet_SelectionChange` or equivalent.

Comment: There is more than 1 row in column "B" and if let's say I select "Camera AXIS check" in the first row, it unhides column "E", but if I select anything else than "Camera AXIS check" in a second row, it hides the whole column "E". I would prefer that the column "E" would then remain unhidden. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AndriusGataveckas See the addition to my answer. I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Amazing, again, appreciate your help.